# mod_rewrite not working

Tags: apache2, php, modules

For some reason I can't get mod_rewrite to work. I have it enabled and it is visible under phpinfo() and I have the appropriate permissions enabled. What's going on?

000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin ****@gmail.com

    ServerName ****.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my rewrite rule for checking...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php?act=(.*)&p=(.*)$ site/$1/$2.html
```

Can anyone spot anything out of the ordinary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you didn't  mention was the module in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load`, which enables the rewrite engine.  If you haven't done this, you need to add a link in the directory `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`; from the directory `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`, enter `ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load` to create a symbolic link to this.

You can also use 'sudo a2enmod rewrite'